# Why does `apt install linux-headers-generic` install old headers for the newest stable kernel?

Tags: pi-4, kernel, driver

I can boot a vanilla pi-4 with `kernel8.img` (Feb 15, 2023) to release `5.15.84-v8+` ...  the pi-4 runs admirably.

```
# ls -ltr /boot/*.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8194604 Feb 15 18:02 /boot/kernel8.img

# uname -r
5.15.84-v8+
```

**But** when I install `linux-headers-generic`, I get the message that version **5.10.162-1** already installed...

```
# apt install linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-arm64' instead of 'linux-headers-generic'
linux-headers-arm64 is already the newest version (5.10.162-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

eg.

```
$ apt list --installed "linux-headers-5.1*.*-"{common,arm64}
Listing... Done
linux-headers-5.10.0-21-arm64/stable-security,now 5.10.162-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-5.10.0-21-common/stable-security,stable-security,now 5.10.162-1 all [installed,automatic]
```

Even more **terrible**: `linux-headers-5.15.84-v8+-arm64` is **missing** from the repo.

How/where can I force `apt` to download the newest stable **linux-headers-5.15.84-v8+-arm64** headers?  (as per the actual boot kernel)

Note: I'm trying to build fresh dkms drivers for zfs, and zfs's build needs the most current headers.

Comment: A similar issue: [Re: Do I install the current "correct" kernel headers? (and how)](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1986779&hilit=zfs+headers#p1986779)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, you can fix it by using

```
 sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

instead of the generic headers. 
That fixed the issue for me and v4l2loopback at least. 

I found the answer at the bottom of [this](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

**test case:** build current stable zfs divers for pi4.

Record current kernel release:

```
$ ls -lt /boot/kernel8.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8194604 Feb 16 09:40 /boot/kernel8.img
$ uname -r
5.15.84-v8+
```

Upgrade to the most current packages:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Prep linux for a build:

```
$ sudo apt install -y build-essential autoconf automake libtool gawk alien fakeroot dkms libblkid-dev uuid-dev libudev-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libaio-dev libattr1-dev libelf-dev python3 python3-dev python3-setuptools python3-cffi libffi-dev python3-packaging git libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

At this point you already have headers for `5.10.0-21`, but sadly these are of not much use for building modules for the `5.15.84-v8+` kernel! :-( ... eg. ...

```
# apt list --installed "linux-headers*"
Listing... Done
linux-headers-5.10.0-21-arm64/stable-security,now 5.10.162-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-5.10.0-21-common/stable-security,stable-security,now 5.10.162-1 all [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-arm64/stable-security,now 5.10.162-1 arm64 [installed]
```

Instead, you must `apt install` the additional `raspberrypi-kernel-headers` package required to build on "Raspberry Pi OS" (aka debian11 on pi4/arm/64)

```
$ sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Download and build the package containing the driver:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/openzfs/zfs
$ cd zfs
$ git checkout master
$ sh autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make -s -j$(nproc)
$ make -s -j$(nproc) deb
```

Install the required packages and test:

```
$ sudo apt install -y $PWD/{zfs,zfs-dkms,libzfs5,libnvpair3,libuutil3}_2.1.99-1734_arm64.deb $PWD/kmod-zfs-`uname -r`_2.1.99-1734_arm64.deb
$ sudo zpool import -a
```

Enable zfs on boot:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable --now zfs-import-scan.service zfs-mount zfs-import.target zfs-zed zfs.target zfs-import-cache.service
```

**Reboot** and check zfs now works OK! (And finds all existing filesystems... if you have any)

```
$ df -PhT -t zfs
Filesystem           Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
zfs_test             zfs       136G  107G   29G  80% /zfs_test
zfs_vault            zfs       2.9T  2.7T  192G  94% /zfs_vault
```

Warning: **Do not run** `rpi-update`, as this appears will install beta/`unstable` kernel-6.0.xx (and fresh firmware) and you will stuck in beta tester land... ;-)

But if you do... DougieLawson: "If you update the kernel with rpi-update you'd need to run rpi-source to get the matching kernel source tree and headers."

eg. If you run `rpi-update` you will get something like:

```
# modprobe zfs
modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/6.xx.xx-v8+
```

Note the `6.0.xx` in `/lib/modules/6.0.xx` in the above.

See also:

- [Building ZFS - by OpenZFS](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Developer%20Resources/Building%20ZFS.html)
- [Do I install the current "correct" kernel headers? (and how)](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1986779&hilit=zfs+headers#p1986779)
- [manjaro: ZFS pool does not load during boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/688359/manjaro-zfs-pool-does-not-load-during-boot-using-zfs-import-cache-zfs-mount-b) - "ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/module/zfs was not met".

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NevilleDNZ/zfs_build_dkms_hints